# Will a Google Cloud SQL database get automatically deleted if vm is stopped or billing account is disconnected?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am trying to understand how to lower my Google Cloud SQL bill.  I have some databases that are not used frequently and store a modest (100MB) amount of data.  I am thinking about stopping the VMs associated with those databases and disconnecting the billing account whenever the application that uses them is not running.  Will my data persist even though the vm is off and the billing account is disconnected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the instance when you are not using it, and this would stop the billing for it without any worries about the information being deleted. This is mentioned over at [this document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/pricing).

Nevertheless, if you disconnect the billing account from the project for a long period of time, or it remains disabled, the instance may be deleted as mentioned over at [this document](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#disable_billing_for_a_project).

I hope you find this information useful.